# Error with Program to detect colliding spheres

Tags: c++

In this program spheres will move around a 3d space that is enclosed by a cube. The spheres will move until they hit a wall or another sphere. If they hit the wall they are destroyed. If they hit another sphere, the smaller sphere will be destroyed.

The sphere's are given in x,y,z coordinates with a radius r and a dx, dy, dz for the movement.

The general gist of the program is to loop through a list of sphere objects and use the distance formula to see if it is less than the radius to detect a collision.

Anyways, I keep getting an error in Visual Studio during runtime saying "list iterator is not incrementable. However, the program does run without errors on the Linux g++ compiler. It looks like the problem occurs when attempting to detect sphere collisions as the program works when the section is commented out.

```
// This is where our spheres are moved
s = sphereList.begin();                     //set iterator to beginning of list

while(s != sphereList.end())                //This loop moves the spheres
{
    bool firstRun = true;
    double x,y,z,r,xj,yj,zj,dist,radii,area1,area2;         //Temp x,y,z,r

    Point newCenter;        //Temp Center for movement calculatio n

    x = s->getX()+s->getdx();
    y = s->getY()+s->getdy();
    z = s->getZ()+s->getdz();
    r = s->getRadius();

    newCenter.setX(x);
    newCenter.setY(y);
    newCenter.setZ(z);

    s->setCenter(newCenter);    //replaces existing sphere with new coordinates

    //check if the sphere has reached the edge of the cube at 0 or 1000 units 
    if(x+r >= MAX_CUBE || x-r <= MIN_CUBE || y+r >= MAX_CUBE || y-r <= MIN_CUBE || z+r >= MAX_CUBE || z-r <= MIN_CUBE)
    {
        cout << "  " << s->getElement() << "         " << (int)time << "         " << "Boundary" << endl;
        s = sphereList.erase(s);
        time = 1 * TIME_VALUE;
    }

    std::list<Sphere>::iterator j = sphereList.begin();         //second iterator
        j++;
    while(j != sphereList.end())
    {
        xj = j->getX();
        yj = j->getY();
        zj = j->getZ();

        dist = sqrt(((x-xj)*(x-xj))+((y-yj)*(y-yj))+((z-zj)*(z-zj)));

        //cout << dist << endl;
        radii = s->getRadius() + j->getRadius();

        if(dist < radii)
        {

            if(s->getRadius() < j->getRadius())
            {
                cout << "  " << s->getElement() << "         " << (int)time << "         " << "Collision" << endl;
                s = sphereList.erase(s);
                time = 1 * TIME_VALUE;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "  " << j->getElement() << "         " << (int)time << "         " << "Collision" << endl;
                j = sphereList.erase(j);
                time = 1 * TIME_VALUE;
                break;
            }
        }
    j++;
    }
    time++;


}
```

Comment: That's an awful lot of code for us to read for one error. Please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: What is the format of the file you are reading from?

Comment: Sorry about that, I shortened the code down to the section I was having trouble with. The file format is a text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `s` and `j` are at the same position in the list, you'll erase `j`, which invalidates `s`.

You shouldn't need to start `j` from the beginning every time as you've already compared it against every element in front of `s`.

I think replacing

```
j = sphereList.begin();
```

with

```
j = s;
```

should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Within the loop below, you are incrementing `i` several times, are you sure you have so many elements?

```
while(i != doubleList.end())
{
```

Comment: Yes, the text file contains coordinates, radius, and movement for a number of spheres.